# Invalid endpoint URL address in proxy serice

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to configure a pass-through proxy service within wso2 integrator in order to test a sample message transport from my PC to an internal server that exposes a specific API.

The endpoint works well with a direct request (through Postman or rest client) but it fails when configuring it as a target endpoint in the proxy.

Does any help please?

Thanks

I'm trying this on my terminal:

```
curl http://<hostname>:<port>/XXX
```

and it responds but the same URL is non-discovered in wso2.

```
curl http://<hostname>:<port>/XXX
```

when trying to capture the communication between wso2-ei and my back-end service, i found that the request from the proxy service is sent to this url : http://:/XXX?wsdl

How can i delete this "?wsdl" please?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding following property before the backend call. **REST_URL_POSTFIX** transport property can used to access the context part of the url. By setting it as an empty string, we can remove additional query parameters such as "?wsdl" appending to the url. Please refer [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX) for details.

```html
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" value="" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

If this does not work, please share your synapse configuration along with the [wire](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html) logs.